# Delete all dynamically created PictureBoxes with the same parent in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox, parent-child, picturebox

I am writing a windows forms application in C# in which i am dynamically creating TextBoxes and PictureBoxes with a Panel as the parent:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Parent = MainPanel;
pb.Name = "pb" + "r" + NumberInRow + "c" + NumberInColumn+ "bi" + buildIndex;
pb.Location = new Point(30 * NumberInRow + 192 * (NumberInRow - 1), 50 * NumberInColumn + 273 * (NumberInColumn - 1));
pb.ImageLocation = ThumbLinks[i];

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Parent = MainPanel;
tb.Name = "tb" + "r" + NumberInRow + "c" + NumberInColumn + "bi" + buildIndex;
tb.Location = new Point(pb.Location.X - 4, pb.Location.Y + pb.Size.Height + 5);
tb.Text = GalleryNames[i];
```

I am trying to delete them with this:

```
foreach (PictureBox pb in MainPanel.Controls)
    {
                MainPanel.Controls.Remove(pb);
    }

foreach (TextBox tb in MainPanel.Controls)
     {
                MainPanel.Controls.Remove(tb);
     }
```

This only seems to work once though.
Visual Studio tells me that it can't convert `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` into `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`.

Is there any way to delete the PictureBoxes and TextBoxes differently?

I've read about something like `MainPanel.Children.Remove();` but it doesn't seem to exist or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: the error you're getting is because the element's type inside the Panel are PictureBox and TextBox, so you can't use a Foreach and cast all of them as PictureBox/TextBox. Besides if remove items from list in a Foreach loop it wont work correctly. If you want to remove all of them then use `while (MainPanel.Controls.Count > 0) MainPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, removing all of them works for my application. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at `MainPanel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()` and `MainPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`. You can use this in conjunction with a `.ToList()` call to avoid modifying an interator while it's still active:

```
var PBs = MainPanel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList();
var TBs = MainPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
foreach (var pb in PBs)
{
    MainPanel.Controls.Remove(pb);
}
foreach (TextBox tb in TBs)
{
    MainPanel.Controls.Remove(tb);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i thought the `PictureBox` in foreach would only look for PictureBoxes.
This is what i was looking for,

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var control in MainPanel.Controls
                        .Where(c => c is PictureBox) || c is TextBox)
{
     MainPanel.Controls.Remove(control);
}
```

This will remove each item of types, both `PictureBox` and `TextBox`. The issue with this code of course is that you are modifying an collection whilst enumerating it.

One approach to resolving this issue could be to build a collection of controls to remove first

```
var controls = MainPanel.Controls.Where(c => c is PictureBox || c is TextBox).ToList();
```

And then to enumerate that collection removing each item from the Panel.

```
foreach (var toRemove in controls)
     MainPanel.Controls.Remove(toRemove);
```

It would further benefit one to make sure that the item is removed from the UI on the correct thread

```
delegate void RemoveControlDelegate(Control controlToRemove);

private void RemoveControl(Control control)
{
   if (InvokeRequired)
   {
       BeginInvoke(new RemoveControlDelegate(RemoveControl), control);
   }
   else
   {
       MainPanel.Controls.Remove(control);
   }
}

foreach (var toRemove in controls)
     RemoveControl(toRemove);
```